# Visualization of object trees in VS

Tags: visual-studio, object, tree, visualization

I am implementing a SPA tree algorithm and is looking for a Visual Studio plug-in that let me visualize objects and their relationships in debug/runtime.

Visualization like:

```
[0]-----[1]
 | \    /
[2] \  /
 |  [4]
[3]  | \
  \  |  [6]
   \[5]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DGML](http://blogs.msdn.com/camerons/archive/2009/01/26/directed-graph-markup-language-dgml.aspx), see a sample [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jasonz/archive/2010/02/02/favorite-vs2010-features-dependency-graphs-and-dgml.aspx). You can author it yourself, it's based on XML. And you can just open it in Visual Studio 2010, you don't need any add-ins. You can create one from Add - New Item - Direct Graph Document. There also is a query language for it DGQL.

Now to see the objects hierarchy you can use Architecture Explorer. But it's static, at design time.

What kind of relations are you looking for at runtime?

Comment: Thanks. I actually found this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/mohamedg/archive/2010/03/02/visual-gcroot-via-dgml.aspx

Which uses gcroot to dump the managed heap into a nice DGML visualization.